# How to read data from arduino in python without showing b' SOMETEXT \r\n'

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino-uno, pyserial

Using python3 and pyserial on a virtualmachine ,Ubuntu 17.10, Ran the code like this "User@user:$ python3 ardui.py".

I'm trying to get rid of the b' ... /r/n' just get text or string for example , I get this on python b' What's 9+10? /r/n' but Im trying to get only the "What's 9 + 10?" how can i get rid of the other text ?

```
int PB = 2;  //Its just a button that when pressed it gets store in the variable buttonState

void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(PB, INPUT);
}

void loop(){
int buttonState = digitalRead(PB):
if(buttonState ==1){
  Serail.println("What's 9 + 10");
  delay(10);
}
else
{
Serial.println("21!");
delay(100);
}
}
```

And the python code is this one:

```
import serial
arduinoSerialData = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
while (1==1):
  if (arduinoSerialData.inWaiting()>0):
    myData = arduinoSerialData.readline()
    print (myData)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert bytes to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)

Comment: so it will be something like myData = arduinoSerialData.readline()(b')

Comment: i'v seen people doing this thing at the end .strip()

Comment: I finally got it working you were right, so for anyone new like me ,having the same problem here is the solution after myData=arduinoSerial.readline() i added .()strip so i'll be like this "myData=arduinoSerial.readline().strip()"

Comment: Then I added a new line just below that one like this "LDecode = myData.decode('UTF-8")" and done got rid of it !!

Answer (score 0):

Just perform a **strip** (which removes white space and line feeds) when you read it in:

```
    myData = arduinoSerialData.readline().strip()
```